# Delimiter for complex commands/bindings in tmux config

Tags: bash, vim, tmux

I am looking for a way to make [the following line](https://gist.github.com/dtrckd/73e5ce017e8c4093822414522412f1f2#file-tmux-conf-L211) right in my tmux config:

```
bind -n S-F12 unbind -n S-Left \; unbind -n S-Right \; unbind -n S-Down \; unbind -n S-Up \; unbind -n M-Left \; unbind -n M-Right \; unbind -n M-Down \; unbind -n M-Up \; bind -n S-F12 source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"  \; display-message "Tmux Vim Mode: DISABLED" \; display-message "Tmux Vim Mode: Enabled"
```

The point is to toggle some bindings when doing `S-F12` and printing a message on success. The thing is that the message "Tmux Vim Mode: DISABLED" is never printed probably due to the ambiguity of the delimiters of the bindings.

Is there a way to make it work ?

ps: I don't want to create another tmux config file and use `source`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might try is

```
bind -n S-F12 unbind -n S-Left \; \
 unbind -n S-Right \; \
 unbind -n S-Down \; \
 unbind -n S-Up \; \
 unbind -n M-Left \; \
 unbind -n M-Right \; \
 unbind -n M-Down \; \
 unbind -n M-Up \; \
 bind -n S-F12 run-shell 'tmux source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"  \; \
                          display-message "Tmux Vim Mode: Enabled"'  \; \
 display-message "Tmux Vim Mode: DISABLED"
```

Make sure `\` is the last character on the line when you use this sort of continuation. Typing <kbd>Shift-F12</kbd> will do the unbinds, and rebind to a `run-shell` that can cope with doing the `source` and `display-message` as a single string inside `''`. I've inverted the messages to what I think you wanted, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Thx, It works. The messages were correct in my sense. When I first press `S-F12`, i disable some tmux movement binding that I actually use in vim. (so the "VIM mode enabled".)